# Best setup/workflow for testing and deploying an application using Google Firebase Hosting and Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I built a small web application (www.suntax.de) with vuejs and hosted on Google Firebase. I use the Firebase Hosting, Database and Functions. I use Functions to do some calculation on the backend.

Everything is running now, but I had some trouble getting there and some things I would like to improve regarding my workflow.
Thus, I would like to explain you what I did and where I struggle now.

First I set up the vuejs applicationd deployed it to firebase. I added my custom domain and everything was doing fine.
Later I implemented the cloud function and want to make a call from my vuejs app.
After `firebase deploy`, I can call this function in the browser and it just works fine:
`https://us-central1-suntax-6d0ea.cloudfunctions.net/calcEEGcompensation?year=2013&month=1&size=10`

Now I thought, that I just call the URL of the function from my vuejs app. But then I got the following error message:
`[Error] Origin * is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

I was then reading that I had to add a `rewrite`section in the `firebase.json`:

Now my firebase.json looks like this:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    // Add the following rewrites section *within* "hosting"
   "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "/calcEEGcompensation", "function": "calcEEGcompensation"
    } ]
  }
}
```

Now I was able to call my firebase function with the following URL:

`https://www.suntax.de/calcEEGcompensation?year=2013&month=1&size=10`

After integrating the above URL in my vuejs application, the application is running fine after deployment to firebase server.

As I want to keep improving the application, I would like to test everything locally before deploying.

I know that I can run firebase hosting and functions locally by:
`firebase serve --only functions,hosting`

However, now my application has the hard coded call to my function `https://www.suntax.de/calcEEGcompensation?year=2013&month=1&size=10` and this again leads to the error `[Error] Origin * is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

But also changing the URL to the local function 
`http://localhost:5001/suntax-6d0ea/us-central1/calcEEGcompensation?year=2013&month=1&size=10`
leads to the error message 
`[Error] Origin * is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Some further reading brought me to the solution with `cors`. So I changed my function to:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

exports.calcEEGcompensation = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        const yearOfCommissioning = req.query.year;
        const monthOfCommissioning = req.query.month;
        const pvsystemsize = req.query.size;

        ...

        res.send("hello");
    });
});
```

This helped and everything works now:
- The deployed application is still running fine.
- I can run the application locally while calling the local function as well as the deployed function. I just have to change the URL of the function.

But this is now my question:
Can I solve this issue in a better way? If I test the vuejs application and the function locally, I have to change the function URL before deployment. And then I have to change it back while testing locally.
I was not able to test my application and function locally without `cors`.

My ideal solution would be to have a setup, that can be fully tested locally and which can be easily deployed with `firebase deploy` without any changes of URLs. Is this possible?

Thanks and best regards,
Christoph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution which is pretty simple and does exactly what I want. I have no idea why I did not figure it out before.
Here is what I did:

I just call the relative URL from my firebase hosting:

`calcEEGcompensation?year=2013&month=1&size=10`

and everything works fine if the rewrites are properly set in `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    // Add the following rewrites section *within* "hosting"
   "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "/calcEEGcompensation", "function": "calcEEGcompensation"
    } ]
  }
}
```

After setting up everything like this, I can just execute `firebase serve --only functions,hosting` and I can test everything locally. 
After executing `firebase deploy`, everything runs smoothly on the server.

I do not need `cors`.

Thanks @wonsuc for your answers.

Comment: It seems I missed what you found. Nice approach!

Answer (score 1):

**Update(For Firebase Hosting):**
Currently there is no workaround you can solve it with Firebase Hosting SDK.
But there is alternative way you can achieve this.

Try below code in your hosting source.

```
if (location.hostname === 'localhost' || location.hostname === '127.0.0.1') {
    console.log('It's a local server!');
}
```

In my opinion, these are best way to check dev environment currently.
Therefore you should use `location.hostname` in your Firebase Hosting, and `server.address()` in Cloud Functions.

And define your Functions end point with constant variable.

```
const DEBUG = location.hostname === 'localhost' || location.hostname === '127.0.0.1';
const FUNCTIONS_ENDPOINT_DEV = 'http://localhost:5001/';
const FUNCTIONS_ENDPOINT_PRD = 'https://us-central1-something.cloudfunctions.net/';
const FUNCTIONS_URL_CALC = 'calcEEGcompensation?year=2013&month=1&size=10';

var endpoint;
if (DEBUG) {
    endpoint = FUNCTIONS_ENDPOINT_DEV + FUNCTIONS_URL_CALC;
} else {
    endpoint = FUNCTIONS_ENDPOINT_PRD + FUNCTIONS_URL_CALC;
}
```

**Original answer(For Cloud Functions for Firebase):**
Have you tried node.js net module's [server.address()](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_address) function?
This method will tell you if your functions code is running on `localhost` or real deployed server.

For examples, you can use like this.

```
const server = app.listen(function() {
    let host = server.address().address;
    let port = server.address().port;

    if (!host || host === '::') {
        host = 'localhost:';
    }

    console.log('Server is running on %s%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your example. That is indeed what I was also thinking of. However, I am wondering if there is a "better" way. For example like using a relative URL instead of the full URL `https://www.suntax.de/calcEEGcompensation?year=2013&month=1&size=10` which would work on the firebase server as well as locally..

Comment: @cmolitor Sorry, I didn't fully understand what your issue is. One question, if your hosting(vue app) is deployed on local, your functions is also deployed on local? I mean, is there situation your hosting and functions are deployed different environment and you have to test as that way? or both local, both server?

Comment: Yes, I would like to run and test the hosting (vue app) as well as the function locally. Furthermore, I would like to deploy and run both on the server. I was just wondering if there is a way to call my function in a way that my setup (hosting and function) works locally for testing as well as on the server after deployment without touching the code.

Comment: @cmolitor Sorry for delay, I updated answer. I hope it would help you.